# Design a system to store custom forms in a database

Tags: architecture

Please forgive me if this is not the right place to ask a design question.

I would like to come up with a design spec for a system that would allow a person to generate a custom form and be able to save it for being filled later by others. I have been looking around for a while and haven’t been able to deduce what exactly should the stack should look like. It’s clear to me that a relational db may not be the right fit for storing such a form(html code). I have been looking into Mongodb that may help me in storing unstructured data, but I am not sure how I can link the JS code for each form(front end validation). So my q is -  What’s would be best stack here to design such a system?

Comment: Why not JSON? You can use the JSON array of values for the custom forms and store them in the database (MySQL)

Comment: There can be different types of form fields - text field, radio button, list/dropdown. How would that look in json? Also, won't it add processing time at the time of render? I am all ears for any suggestion, just trying to make sure the architecture would fit the problem here i.e. storing custom forms.